# Finding position of a point in Cartesian coordinate by knowing its distance from 3 known points.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is is possible to find the X,Y coordinates of a point in Cartesian coordinates, if we have the knowledge about 3 known points and the distance between known points with unknown point?

[image]

So lets say the anchor1 is at [5,5], anchor2 is at [30,460] and anchor3 is at [150,800].

What would be the equation for [x,y] for the green dot if we know d1,d2 and d3.

This is what I know so far:
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is triangulation.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried?, what are your thoughts on this?,where have you stuck.Sharing your work would help the users to understand what you are asking and where you need help. HAPPY MATH SOLVING.

Comment: If the three known points are **collinear** the answer is no. Two points and the associated distances are **almost** enough. Draw the circles with these points as centres and the distances as radii, The two circles meet at $2$ points. So there is only a small amount of ambiguity about the location of our mystery point. It is settled by the third item of information, **if** the three given points are not collinear.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, can you explain why is it not possible to determine the location of the point if the anchors are collinear? I can still visualise 3 circles centred at each anchor and having the point as the common solution to them. (Like, the point lying on the common radical axis of the circles)

Comment: Let the anchors be $(-3,0)$ (distance $5$) and $(3,0)$ (distance $5$) and $(0,0)$ (distance $4$). Both $(0,4)$ and $(0,-4)$ satisfy these distance constraints. I produced a specific example, but the same issue arises with any $3$ collinear anchors.

Comment: I thought of that myself - of having multiple points satisfying the condition. But then I thought it was *okay* to have multiple such points since that's what OP is asking - *"Is is possible to find the X,Y coordinates of a point in Cartesian coordinates, if we have the knowledge about 3 known points and the distance between known points with unknown point"*. The only difference is that 2 points satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint. (But double check my work to be sure). Let the green dot be at $(x_0,y_0)$ and the known points and their distances to the green dot be given by $(x_i,y_i$) and $d_i$, $i=1,2,3$. What you know is that

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
x_1^2 - 2x_0 x_1 + x_0^2 + y_1^2 - 2y_0 y_1 + y_0^2 - d_1^2 & = & 0 \\
x_2^2 - 2x_0 x_2 + x_0^2 + y_2^2 - 2y_0 y_2 + y_0^2 - d_2^2 & = & 0 \\
x_3^2 - 2x_0 x_3 + x_0^2 + y_3^2 - 2y_0 y_3 + y_0^2 - d_3^2 & = & 0, \\
\end{array}
$$

which gives the following linear system:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & -2x_1 & -2y_1 \\ 
1 & 1 & -2x_2 & -2y_2 \\ 
1 & 1 & -2x_3 & -2y_3
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_0^2 \\ y_0^2 \\ x_0 \\ y_0
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
d_1^2 - x_1^2 - y_1^2 \\
d_2^2 - x_2^2 - y_2^2 \\
d_3^2 - x_3^2 - y_3^2
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the anchor points $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$. Assume they're not collinear.

The points that are at a distance $d_1$ from anchor $A_1$ lie on a circle (call it $C_1$) with center at $A_1$ and radius $d_1$. Similarly, points that are at a distance $d_2$ from anchor $A_2$ lie on a circle $C_2$.

If the measurements are correct, the circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ will intersect. There will be two intersection points, in general; call these points $P_1$ and $P_2$. Ask again if you need help calculating these two intersection points.

Now just check the distances from $P_1$ and $P_2$ to $A_3$. Presumably one of these two distances will be $d_3$. If so, you're done. If not, then the measurements are wrong.

This all assumes that the points are in 2D. Things are different in 3D.