# How to find coordinates of point in 3D given few points

Tags: matlab

How to find coordinates of point in 3D given coordinates of few(more than 3 non linear/noncoplaner) points and distance from desired point using MATLAB?

suppose given five points are:
    [2.6643    1.4664    0.3019]
    [7.1360    1.4661    1.7333]
    [5.3205   -3.1543    0.5792]
    [3.1621   -1.1489   -2.4490]
    [8.0418   -0.6020   -0.1050]

and their respective distances from point(x,y,z) are:
    0.0376,
    0.0418,
    0.1882,
    0.0753,
    0.0538

How can i find x, y and z using MATLAB?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472548/finding-position-of-a-point-in-cartesian-coordinate-by-knowing-its-distance-from). The answer is easily extended to 3-D. Once you have the matrices set up, use the "\" operator to solve the system.

Answer (score -1):

Write the sum of the square distances as a function, then use one of its minimization routines.